# Summing only the latest values for the entries

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would like to sum the values of only the latest entries. Please see example below:

| Deal name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Green grass | 110 |
| Firebolt | 220 |
| Green grass | 230 |

The formula would only sum the last two to get 450 because it is taking only the latest value for each entry.

Anyone have an idea for the right formula here? Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using two helper columns, then here's one solution.

Helper_1 column: Count the number of times the Deal Name has appeared in your list, from A2 down to the current row.

```
Cell C2 formula:  =COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)
```

Helper_2 column: If the max value for the deal name equals the value in the first helper column, then TRUE, else FALSE.

```
Cell D2 formula: =C2=MAXIFS($C$2:$C$4,$A$2:$A$4,A2)
```

Drag 'em down.

Lastly, here's the SUM formula for cell G2, which is summing your values when Column D is true.

```
    =SUMIFS(B2:B4,D2:D4,"TRUE")
```

[image]

You may be able to modify this down to one helper column should you find time.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel 365, you can use UNIQUE and XLOOKUP:

```
=SUM(XLOOKUP(UNIQUE(A2:A4),A2:A4,B2:B4,0,0,-1))
```

Basically you take the array of UNIQUE deal names, and XLOOKUP the values in reverse direction (bottom-up) for the first matching entry. Because UNIQUE provides an array output, XLOOKUP also returns all the values for each name in an array, which is added up with SUM.